# How to determine Cocoa (OS X) application start time

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an app for OS X, and I need to grab messages from the log to send back to our server for analysis/troubleshooting. I know I can use the Apple System Log (ASL) functions to get what I want, but would like to only get log messages for the current session. I could grab the time in my AppDelegate init method:

```
    // now minus one second
    NSDate *startTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-1];
```

But was wondering if the system might have a more accurate record of when the app started. I've looked at NSProcessInfo, but don't see anything in there that would be relevant. Is there a way to determine a process' start time other than just recording the time in the app itself?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I do not have a Mac handy to verify if this works in OS X, but C standard library offers the [`clock()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/clock/) function in the `<time.h>` header, which could be used together with `CLOCKS_PER_SEC` to get the number of seconds that passed since the time when your program has launched.

**EDIT**

This should get you the time within one second from your program's launch, no matter at what point you invoke it:

```
NSDate *startTime = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:-clock()/CLOCKS_PER_SEC];
```

Comment: This doesn't really provide any advantage over the NSDate based approach the OP mentions. I think he's looking for a way to read the system's record of the app's launch, without having to store the date upon launch himself.

Comment: @AndrewMadsen That *is* what `clock()` does - according to the documentation at the link, it "returns the number of clock ticks elapsed since the program was launched." The name is misleading, though.

Comment: This method at least provides a more accurate measure of the app start time than what I was using before. Thanks!

Comment: Indeed, sorry about the misinformation! Answer duly upvoted :).